# Add ContextMenu to MenuBarExtra SwiftUI macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui

I want to be able to show a context menu when I right click my `MenubarExtra` app, similar to the Figma app behaviour for macOS:

[image]

Note that the left clic is showing the actual MenubarExtra window.

Comment: Do you really only want to use `MenuBarExtra()` ?
Currently, the available approach appears to be using `NSStatusBar` through `AppDelegate`

Comment: Yes I want to stick with `MenuBarExtra`, If I can't add this feature to it, I will leave it for now.

Answer (score 2):

The closest solution would be using [MenuBarExtraAccess](https://github.com/orchetect/MenuBarExtraAccess).

You can directly access the NSStatusItem via

```swift
.menuBarExtraAccess(isPresented: $isMenuPresented) { statusItem in // <-- the magic ✨
    // access status item or store it in a @State var
}
```

and implement a right-click listener with:

```swift
// MARK: Right-mouse icon click
        NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .rightMouseDown) { [weak self] event in
            if event.window == self?.statusItem.button?.window {
                WLLNotificationCenter.Keys.statusbarDidClick.send(.rightMouseClicked)
                let menu = StatusBarContextMenu()
                menu.popUp()
            }
            return event
        }
```